# Como eu faço pra pegar esse 'title' dentro de um <h3> com o BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Estou pegando essa classe no Beautifulsoup e preciso colher o título dentro do a que está dentro do h3

```
<article class="product_pod">
    <div class="image_container">
    <a href="catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html"><img alt="A Light in the Attic" class="thumbnail" src="media/cache/2c/da/2cdad67c44b002e7ead0cc35693c0e8b.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
    <p class="star-rating Three">
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    </p>
    <h3><a href="catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html" title="A Light in the Attic">A Light in the ...</a></h3>
    <div class="product_price">
    <p class="price_color">£51.77</p>
    <p class="instock availability">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i>
```

Eu já tentei pegar tanto buscando tanto pelo 'h3' quanto pelo 'a' mas parece que o primeiro registro de 'a' não tem o título e isso causa um none no resultado

eu já tentei

```
title = soup.find('a') e -> h3
print(title.get('title')
```

e

```
title = soup.find('a') e -> h3
print(title['title'])
```

e também quando eu dou .findAll no 'a' ele retorna apenas o href

Comment: Esse trecho em HTML é tudo o que foi tratado pelo `soup`? Lembre-se que `soup.find('a')` vai retornar o primeiro `<a>` que tiver.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para acessar o atributo **title** é necessário setar o parâmetro **title** do método **find_all** como True e extrair as informações da lista resultante.

Exemplo:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<article class="product_pod">
    <div class="image_container">
    <a href="catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html"><img alt="A Light in the Attic" class="thumbnail" src="media/cache/2c/da/2cdad67c44b002e7ead0cc35693c0e8b.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
    <p class="star-rating Three">
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    </p>
    <h3><a href="catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html" title="A Light in the Attic">A Light in the ...</a></h3>
    <div class="product_price">
    <p class="price_color">£51.77</p>
    <p class="instock availability">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

Utilize o método **find_all** para capturar o texto que você deseja:

```py
for r in soup.find_all("a", title=True):
    print(r['title'])

# A Light in the Attic
# ...
```

Comment: `title` não é uma *tag*, é um *atributo*. O resultado de `find_all` não é um vetor, mas uma lista. E se o objetivo é pegar o primeiro item da lista, bastaria o método `find`.

Comment: @sourcream, muito obrigado pelas correções. Realmente me enganei chamando a tag `title` de atributo e também chamando uma lista de vetor... Sobre o **find_all**, pensei em colocar ele ao invês de **find** pois imaginei que ele precisaria pegar essas informações em mais de um local do html.

Comment: Obrigado Matheus e sourcream, ajudaram bastante

Answer (score -1):

Levando em consideração que tem *n* catalogos com a classe `product_pod`...

```
from collections import namedtuple

row = namedtuple('Row', 'title price')
catalog_list = soup.findAll('article', {'class': 'product_pod'})
[row(x.find('h3').find('a')['title'], 
     x.find('p', {'class': 'price_color'}).text
 ) for x in catalog_list
]
```

Coloquei o preço também, mas os outros deixei de lado por não ser explícito a forma que funciona.